# How to get the percent change of values in a dataframe while caring about NaN values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
   Date                 A                
   2015-01-01          10               
   2015-01-02          14               
   2015-01-05          NaN               
   2015-01-06          NaN                
   2015-01-07          5
   2015-01-10          1  
   2015-01-11          NaN  
   2015-01-12          21  
   2015-01-14          13
```

And I would like to get a data frame with the pct change in the data frame only if this two values are adjacent and not separated by NaN.

i.e. I would like this:

```
        Date                 A                             
       2015-01-02         0.2857                           
       2015-01-10         -0.8  
       2015-01-14         -0.38
```

But if I do: `df.pct_change()` it will return the pct change between 14 and 5 for the 201-01-07

Comment: Did you try passing `fill_method=None`?

Comment: @ayhan, this is perfect! `df.assign(A=df.A.pct_change(fill_method=None)).dropna()` I think you should post it as an answer!

Comment: @MaxU Thanks. Looks like it is solved already so let me leave it as a comment (I didn't know if Date was an index, if this was a Series etc that's why I didn't answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `pct_change` and `shift`:

```
df.pct_change()[df.shift(1).notnull()].dropna()
```

Output:

```
                   A
Date                
2015-01-02  0.400000
2015-01-10 -0.800000
2015-01-14 -0.380952
```

Answer (score 3):

use `cumsum` on `isnull` to find groups to `groupby`

```
s = df.set_index('Date').A
c = n.cumsum()
s.groupby(c).pct_change().dropna().reset_index()

        Date         A
0 2015-01-02  0.400000
1 2015-01-10 -0.800000
2 2015-01-14 -0.380952
```