# Is there a way to skip observation using Pandas pct_change() function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Took a look at these and they don't really answer my question:

- [Pandas pct_change with data containing NaN results in nonsensical values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64960285/pandas-pct-change-with-data-containing-nan-results-in-nonsensical-values)
- [How to get the percent change of values in a dataframe while caring about NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43527554/how-to-get-the-percent-change-of-values-in-a-dataframe-while-caring-about-nan-va)
- [python pandas - calculate percentage change using last non-na value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54372352/python-pandas-calculate-percentage-change-using-last-non-na-value)

I have a large DataFrame, and would like to calculate `pct_change()` for each column.  I would like the result to skip nan values so that it's equivalent to this:

```
for i in df.columns:
    _pct = df[i].dropna().pct_change()
```

And then for rows where the originally value was nan, the `pct_change()` value will also be nan.  In other words, if I have:

```
price = [1, nan, 1.1, 1.155, nan, 1.0395]
```

I want:

```
pct_change = [nan, nan, 0.1, 0.05, nan, -0.1]
```

Is there a built in way to do this or do I have to create my own loop to do it, i.e. loop through each column, do pct change, then replace values with nan?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `pct_change` with the nan in the columns then mask these cells so something like

```
df.pct_change().where(df.notna())
```

with an example it gives:

```
nan = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'price': [1, nan, 1.1, 1.155, nan, 1.0395],
    'price2': [1, nan, nan, 1.155, nan, 1.0395]
})
print(df.pct_change().where(df.notna()))
#    price  price2
# 0    NaN     NaN
# 1    NaN     NaN
# 2   0.10     NaN
# 3   0.05   0.155
# 4    NaN     NaN
# 5  -0.10  -0.100
```